# How to determine the order from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a restaurant with many employees and each employee has many customer ratings.

I want to create a stats page that shows the employees ordered by their monthly ratings average.

In the employee model:

```
def avg_rating
   date = Date.today
   ratings_total = self.ratings.sum(:score, :conditions => {:created_at => (date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month)}).to_f
   ratings_count = self.ratings.count(:conditions => {:created_at => (date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month)}).to_f
   return (ratings_total/ ratings_count)
end
```

In the restaurant controller I have:

```
def restaurant_stats
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
  @employees = @restaurant.employees.all
end
```

In the restaurant stats view:

```
<table>
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= employee.name %></td>
  <td><%= employee.avg_rating %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I'm not sure how to get the employees in the correct order? I assume I would have to retrieve the values in the correct order in the restaurant_stats action instead of just @restaurant.employees.all but I'm not sure how to because of the functions used in the employees model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do, from the controller:

```
@employees = @restaurant.employees.all.sort_by {|employee| employee.avg_rating}
```

or more concisely

```
@employees = @restaurant.employees.all.sort_by(&:avg_rating)
```

Note that this will load all employees in memory for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the restaurant controller:

```
@employees = @restaurant.employees.all.sort {|x,y| y.avg_rating <=> x.avg_rating }
```

or

```
@employees = @restaurant.employees.all.sort_by(:avg_rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create an array and sort it
I think below works but haven't checked it

```
@employees = @restaurant.employees.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.avg_rating ]}
@employees.sort!{ |a,b| (a[1] <=> b[1]) }
```